# (URL) String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, imageview

update: The code is fine. It was simply a wrong pointer to the database.

I'm using JSONParser method to make http request to get JSON data and returns a JSONObject from database. There is no problem getting the JSONObject and display the String such as the name and email, but It does not retrieving the URL of the images. 
I don't get any error but it's just displaying empty fields.

However, if I make this line from

```
String imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG);
```

to this

```
String imageURL = "http://mywebsite.com/images/photo1.png";
```

It works fine.

```
//URL to make request
private static final String url_veiw_directory = "http://www.myweb.com/android/include/directory_detail_me.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DIRECTORY = "directory";
private static final String TAG_ID = "user_id";
private static final String TAG_IMG = "photo"; // Image URLs stored in the DB
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

//Get JSONObject by httpRequest
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_veiw_directory, "GET", params);

Log.d("my profile", json.toString());

 if (success == 1) {

    JSONArray directoryObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DIRECTORY);  

    JSONObject directory = directoryObj.getJSONObject(0);

    //User Image                            
    int loader = R.drawable.loader; 

    String imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG);                         
    ImageView imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());        
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, loader, imagePhoto);

    //User Name and Email                           
    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);                            

    txtName.setText(directory.getString(TAG_NAME));
    txtEmail.setText(directory.getString(TAG_EMAIL));

//Image Loader Class

public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ImageUtils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What string does the code `directory.getString(TAG_IMG)` produce? Log it and find out why it doesn't match the string you want. Then find a way to make it acceptable.

Comment: @TheZ, i'm sorry but i'm sort of a newbie. could you kindly explain little in details?

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of the JSON string returned by the server?

Comment: @Kyle, thank you for reading my post. Did you meant my Logcat? well..if I retrieve with TextView like the name and email, it will display the URL path of the user's images. hope i answered it to yours. please let me know

Comment: @nana I mean post an example of what the server response looks like.  For example `{"field1":"abc","field2":"http://www.url.com"}` Something like that.

Comment: @Kyle, I just found out that it doesn't print out the value of the image from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason is that `imageURL` string is ether empty or what maybe more likely (since you are pulling it from DB) it's escaped to the form that makes it unusable as URL. I would suggest to print it out and see the value at which point you probably can unescape it or do some character substitution

You may see something like `http%3A//mywebsite.com/images/photo1.png`

Comment: Bostone, thank you for your comment. It seems like it doesn't get the value from the database..but it's wired because i can print out the value if i retrieve as textview string.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and see the value of the string? Better yet to see your whole directory object? Also - what is a datatype in db? Are you storing your JSON as string or some sort of binary?

Comment: yes if i print the value by change it to TextView, it returns the URL address to the image.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you edit your question and post the solution at the bottom so it may help someone else?